# Tag Info data from the Stack Overflow data dump

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-dump

Where can I get the [*tag info*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) data?

Is it available in the Stack Overflow [data dump](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange)? (I've only been able to find the tags and their counts so far.)

Answer (score 4):

All that is in the `Posts` table. You can get the relevant row ids from the `Tags` table. For example:

```
select * from Tags where TagName = 'javascript'
```

will produce

> [image]

You can do joins or direct lookups from there, depending on what you want.

---

Whoops, you said "data dump" and my late-night brain read "data explorer". Still, the principle is the same. `Tags.xml` file contains information about the tags that includes the Name and the ids of the wiki and the wiki excerpt posts. You can then look up those ids in `Posts.xml` to get the actual content.

For most sites, the data dump is just in one file. Stack Overflow is too big for that, so it's split over multiple files. You will need both `stackoverflow.com-Tags.7z` and `stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z` to get what you need.

(But really, unless you need offline access, I'd just run SQL queries against the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) instead. It's more up to date than the data dump, too.)

Comment: Hi Adam, Thank you for your answer! I'm interested in the "tag info" page content, in other words, the description of the tag, please see the first link I've mentioned above. Perhaps the WikiPostId or the ExcerptPostId will take me to the tag info data ?

Comment: Adam's saying that the page content is in the Posts table. The row with id `3607052` for example would have the `javascript`'s wiki.

Comment: @average Whoops, sorry, I misread your question last night. Updated the answer with info relevant to the data dump.

Comment: I still don't get it. `Tags.xml` contains the tags with their id's but in `Posts.xml` I only see posts, not the wiki description. @GeorgeDuckett I don't see that id in the `Posts.xml` table. What am I missing?

Comment: @hipoglucido: `Tags.xml` will have a `WikiPostId` attribute that will tell you the id of the post in `Posts.xml` that contains the tag wiki.